# Xcode 7 error on appcelerator appc 5.0.2/ titanium sdk 5.0.0.GA or 5.0.1.GA or 3.5.1.GA

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, xcode7

I have a freshly installed 10.10 os which has all new xcode 7 and latest appcelerator installs. 
Whenever I a building one app using xcode 7, simulator 9, titanium 5.0.0.GA or 5.0.1.GA etc it gives me the below error.

```
[ERROR] :   BUILD FAILED 
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/YALLA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/YALLA.build/Objects-normal/i386/WatchSessionModule.o Classes/WatchSessionModule.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

Funny thing is that it runs just fine in 4.1.0.GA
I have tried all different sdks, reinstalled them and still no luck.

Comment: Did you solve this? Encountered the same error now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your titanium sdk folder. Go to the version you are building your app in.

Generally its in your namespace.
/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.2.1.GA/iphone/Classes/

Open the file WatchSessionModule.h
Change the below line of code

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/watchConnectivity.h>
```

to

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
```

Clean, Build and Run Your Application. You are good to go.